# 5 way wiring question

Tags: switch, light

I’m changing light switches to decora from toggle.

I have 4 switches to one light fixture where 4 of the 3 switches have 5 wires and the 4th switch has 3.

- 1: 2 red 2 black 1 ground
- 2: 2 red 2 black 1 ground
- 3: 2 red 2 white 1 ground
- 4: 1 red 2 black 1 ground

If a 5 way requires 2 4 way switches and 2 3 way switches - which gets 4 way switch? What do I do with the extra wire on the switch were I put a 3 way decora?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. This information could have several meanings, especially in the 1st and 4th switch.   What we need is photos of the wiring.  Wire color is essentially meaningless in 3/4 way wiring, but *pay very close attention* to **screw color**.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your descriptions: *I have 4 switches to one light fixture where 4 of the 3 switches*  Do you mean 3 of the 4 switches?  And then you go on: *If a 5 way requires 2 4 way switches and 2 3 way switches*  A five-way system requires five switches - you list only four.

Comment: There is still a switch to find, unless it was previously removed from the circuit.  In standard multiway switched, each “end” will be a 3-way, and all the switches in between will be 4-way.  If you have an extra wire where you want to put the Decora switch, then you bought the wrong switch, you need a Decora 4-way, not 3-way.

Comment: @Tyson we can't say that, because we don't know what the 2 blacks are doing in switch 1.  It's entirely possible both blacks go to the same 3-way common, and one is simply carrying power *onward* to another switch or load.

Comment: @Harper reading again, I still reach the same conclusion based on the very last question OP asks, _“What do I do with extra wire where I put a 3-way decora?”_ He bought the wrong switch.